# Create timestamp with a specified month in Smarty

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, smarty

I am populating a simple HTML `select` list in a Smarty template with month names. A timestamp object is passed to the template. I would like the passed in timestamp month to be the default value of the `select`. The passed value could be passed in as an `int` (1,2,3,etc...) or a `string` (jan,feb,mar,etc...).

To set a default, selected value I need to compare the passed in timestamp month to a timestamp I created in the template. For example, to compare to just the current month I would do something like this:

```
<option {if $smarty.now|date_format:"%b" = $passedInTimestamp['month']}selected{/if}>
    text
</option>
```

`$smarty.now` will only work for the current month obviously. My `<option>` tag is inside a for loop, looping from 1 to 12. How can I create a timestamp with a specific month to compare to the passed in month?

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: @FouadFodail Haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, this is what you need :

```
<select>
{for $i=1 to 12}
    <option {if '1-'|@cat:$i:'-':'Y'|date|@strtotime|date_format:"%b" == $passedInTimestamp['month']}selected{/if}>
        {$i}
    </option>
{/for}
</select>
```

First, I created a date string for months using [cat](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.cat.tpl) modifier :

```
{'1-'|@cat:$i:'-':'Y'|date}
// will output 
// 1-1-2013   1-2-2013   1-3-2013 ....
```

Then I used [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) modifier to convert it to timstamp

```
{'1-9-2013'|@strtotime}
// will output 1377986400
```

Finally I used `date_format:"%b"` as you did above to compare it to your passed in timestamp month.

Comment: In your link to the `cat` documentation they do not use an `@` symbol or a colon after the `cat` keyword. Why do you here?

Comment: The `@` is a bad habit I used to. In Smarty 2 we had to use `@` to apply a modifier to an array. Now it is ignored with Smarty 3. Just remove it.
In the cat link that I have provided they use colon after cat keyword. See `{$articleTitle|cat:' yesterday.'}`.
In Smarty the colon is used to pass parameters to the modifier.